# How can I restrict board editing access to team members only in Azure DevOps Boards?

Tags: azure-devops

For Azure DevOps projects that have multiple teams (where each team has their own board), is it possible to allow team members to edit (move work items, create work items,... etc) their own team's board, but not other teams' boards, while giving them read access to other teams' boards?

If it is possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you could create a customized team in "Area" path, in this customized team you can make some users only have "View" permission for the specified work items(in this customized team Area like pic c.) by editing in "Security".
(Here is the [doc:Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and steps for reference.)

a.

[image]

b.

[image]

c.In "Permissions", you should set 'Allow' to "View work items in this node" only, and all the other options should be set 'Deny'.

[image]

d.

[image]